AzureFileCopy@6 pipeline Task failing
The AzureFileCopy@6 pipeline task is failing with the following error:
"Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "Method not found: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.get_SerializerSettings()'." 

We are utilizing Service connection type - Azure Resource Manager using workload identity federation with openid connect.

According to my SO answer It seems that Workload Identity isn't supported yet. Instead, you can utilize Azure Resource Manager connection with service principal authentication or a regular service connection. Assign the appropriate roles, such as Azure Storage Blob Data contributor or Azure Storage Blob Data owner, to the service connection on the Storage account. Alternatively, you can directly use a SAS token with restricted roles in your AzCopy URL.
Assigned Storage Blob Data Owner role at the Storage Account level to my Azure Service principal added as a Service connection in Azure Devops:-

Azure Devops Service connection:-

Azure DevOps yaml code:-
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '6.x'
    installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet

- task: AzureFileCopy@4
  inputs:
    SourcePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/SampleApp48'
    azureSubscription: 'PowershellSid'
    Destination: 'AzureBlob'
    storage: 'siliconstrg532'
    ContainerName: 'data'

Output:-


AzureFileCopy@6 is working fine when we try to copy HTML files, but it is not working when we try to copy JSON files.            Getting "Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "Method not found: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.get_SerializerSettings()'." @SiddeshDesai
